# No build stage in current context - Docker file

Tags: docker, docker-image

I have developed a webapplication using struts with sql. I want to deploy my webapp into ecs using aws pipeline. Using docker for the build environment, While running the command,

`docker build -t mydocker .`

I am getting below error

*Sending build context to Docker daemon  46.59kB Error response from
daemon: No build stage in current context*

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER My Name "myname@somecompany.com"
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install nginx -y
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Please help me build an image. 
Please post the dockerfile commands what i should mention.

Comment: Can you share your docker-file? Your question is not formatted properly also

Answer (score 0):

DockerFile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER My Name "myname@somecompany.com"
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install nginx -y
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

This is the command using which you can build your docker-image.

```
docker build - < Dockerfile
```

Comment: Hi Shastri, I ve created Dockerfile and pasted the above comments. I am getting the same error as "Sending build context to Docker daemon  58.88kB
Error response from daemon: No build stage in current context" when i used the comment docker build - < Dockerfile

Comment: It works in my machine, I use 
Docker version 18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40

Comment: Hi...Initially i created as dockerfile. Now i have corrected as Dockerfile. Image has built. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Name of your file should be `Dockerfile` instead of any other naming like `dockerfile`, `dockerFile`, etc.